# How to deal with a company that ghosted me?

Tags: job-search, united-states

I got a verbal job offer. The offer was repeated on two separate occasions. It wasn't conditional. It was a clearly stated job offer.

I was promised a written contract within a few days.

And then the company ghosted me. They haven't contacted me again. The recruiter hasn't replied to my contact attempts. I have never received the contract.

It's a big, well-known company.

What is the best way to deal with that? Should I just forget it and apply again in a few months as if nothing happened? Should I try to explain the situation by contacting everybody I talked to during the interview process explaining the situation? Let's assume my goal is to work there.

P.S. My ghosting definitely isn't related to any background checks or similar. As far as I know there are no shocking videos on me and google search doesn't show any information I would be ashamed of.

Comment: Is the recruiter internal to the company to which you applied, or a third-party recruiter?

Answer (score 6):

I am sorry to hear that. There is pretty much nothing you can do about it, if the person you talked to won't reply, and all you have to go on is a verbal offer.

Wash off the disappointment and get back to grinding the job listings. Good luck!